# Facing issues while installing pycld2 in mac os 10.15.6. It says failed building wheel for pycld2

Tags: pip, conda, macos-catalina, llvm-clang, python-wheel

After creating venv in vscode, I have installed pip and then trying to install requirements.txt file using pip after cloning the repo from github. While other requirements are installed successfully, there is an issue while the system tries to install pycld2 with the following error

```
>     error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1   error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycld2
  Running setup.py clean for pycld2
Failed to build pycld2
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for pycld2 which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above.
```

I have tried updating the clang version and also gcc. And also installed wheel using 'pip3 install wheel'

```
    gcc version : 10.2.0
 clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Please let me know what am I missing out. Thanks in advance